Pgpool 2 with aws aurora
I am Following the pgpool setup for aurora cluster( https://www.pgpool.net/docs/42/en/html/example-aurora.html) which is specific to one region. But for multi region global cluster how can I configure the backends so that writes are sent to single writer in primary region and reads in respective region read replicas. Also post failover the primary writer switches to a different region and how can pgpool point to writer in new region without restarting.
I tried to configure 2 backend, backend 0 is primary writer endpoint, backend 1 is reader endpoint and during failover I try to attach new backend which is the new writer but doesn't seem to updating the primary node to new writer
